# Unable to get values of unbound fields in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get values from gridview.

I use a stored procedure to set the datasource for it, let's just say that the gridview uses dynamic pivot colums so I can't create a bound field for them.

Here is my code trying to get the textbox value and its header value

```
protected void dgvTask_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow selectedRow = grid.SelectedRow;

    int rowIndex = grid.SelectedIndex;
    int selectedCellIndex = int.Parse(this.SelectedGridCellIndex.Value);

    TextBox txtLogs = (TextBox)selectedRow.Cells[selectedCellIndex].FindControl("txtdata");
    string cellValue = txtLogs.Text;
    string headerValue = grid.HeaderRow.Cells[selectedCellIndex].Text;

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + selectedCellIndex + "')", true);
    bindDgvTask();
}
```

I tried also to use

```
string cellValue = grid.SelectedRow.Cells[selectedCellIndex].Text;
```

to get the cell value but both of these returns these error

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

`selectedRow` cannot be wrong because it only returns value of the row selected.
as I check `selectedCellIndex` it also return correct value base on what I clicked.

But when I tried to use `row[0].cells[0]` which is the only boundfield I set

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task">
        <ControlStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" ForeColor="Black" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

It returns correct values.

So now I am puzzled whether I'm doing the retrieving of values the wrong way or just there are different approach on getting values for unbound field.

Thanks in advance